# If $A$ and $B$ have independent columns, prove that $B^TA$ is invertible

Tags: linear-algebra, inverse, matrix-rank

> If $A=[u_1\cdots u_r]$ and $B=[v_1\cdots v_r]$ have independent columns, prove that $B^TA$ is invertible, where $u_i,v_i\in\mathbb{R}^n, n\geq r$.

If $A,B$ have independent columns then $Ax=0\implies x=0$ and $By=0\implies y=0$.

I can also prove that $rank(B^TA)\leq \min(rank(B^T),rank(A))=r$

We have to prove, $B^TAx=0\implies x=0$, it would be helpful to get a hint on how to approach this.

Note: This is needed to derive the expression for an oblique projection matrix in the form $P=A(B^TA)^{-1}B^T$, where $\{u_1,\cdots,u_r\}$ is a basis for the range of P, i.e., $Range(P)$ and $\{u_1,\cdots,u_r\}$ is a basis for the rowspace of P, i.e, $N^\perp$, and the vectorspace $V=Range(P)\oplus Kernel(P)$

Please check [Page 13](https://people.math.osu.edu/costin.10/5101/Orthog%20p12-15.pdf) for the proof.

Comment: If you set $u_i = e_i$ and $v_i = e_{r+i}$ where $2r \leq n$ and $\{e_i : 1 \leq i \leq n\}$ is any orthogonal basis of $\mathbb{R}^n$ (e.g. the standard basis), then $B^TA = 0_{r\times r}$ is the zero matrix... Are we missing some assumptions on $A$ and $B$?

Comment: @BrianMoehring I have updated OP, please check.

Comment: The assumption is that the column space of $A$ together with the orthocomplement of the column space of $B$ span the ambient space.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that $x\in \ker B^TA$ is equivalent to $Ax \in \ker B^T$. Since $A$ has independent columns, if $x$ is non-zero, then $Ax$ is a non-zero vector in the column space of $A$. Being in the null space of $B^T$ is the same as being in the orthogonal complement of the column space of $B$
(since $B^Tx=0 \Leftrightarrow y^TB^Tx=0 \text{ for all } y \Leftrightarrow \langle x, By\rangle=0 \text{ for all } y$ ).

Then $Ax$ is in the intersection of column space of $A$ and the orthogonal complement of the column space of $B$. But if these two have non-trivial intersection, their sum has dimension which is insufficient to span the ambient space ($\dim V+W=\dim V+ \dim W- \dim V\cap W $, which in our case gives at most $r+(n-r)-1=n-1$). Thus the only $x$ that can be in $\ker B^TA$ is the zero $x$.

Comment: I think columns of $B$ need not have to be independent for this condition to be true, right ?

Comment: They do. It depends a bit on what you assume. If you assume that the columns of A and orthocomplement of columns of B SPAN ambient space, then we need the independence of columns of B. Because if columns of B are not independent, the dimension of orthocomplement of the column space of B would be bigger than n-r, and the final part would not work (just think of the case when B is the zero matrix).

Comment: If, on the other hand,  you assume the columns of A and orthocomplement of columns of B HAVE DIRECT SUM which is the ambient space, then the independence of columns of B follows from the independence of columns of A by dimension counting (you can't have n-space be direct sum of r space and something more than n-r-dimensional). But if you make the stronger direct sum assumption, you can stop after the first sentence of the second paragraph.